# Django form data isn't being inserted into postgres but there are no errors

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to insert data from a Django form into a Postgres table. There are no errors but it's not being inserted and the redirect to the thank you page is happening so it appears to be going through the method without an issue.

```
def email(request):


    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            m = MyUser(email=email, city=city, registration_date=datetime.now())
            m.save()
            return redirect('thanks')
    return render(request, "email.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: indentation matters. Please edit your post to be indented exactly the same way that your code is

Comment: It is already indented as the code is but the first line isn't and should be more over to the left but everything else is. When I tried to adjust the first line, other things became unindented.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I will try harder to make the indentation work next time. I tried to copy in again my code again from the original and still it had the same problem.

Comment: can you add the following line to just after m.save: `print 'saved with id', m.pk`

Comment: I got saved with id 13

Comment: And if I enter the form again I get saved with id 14. So it appears to be going somewhere I believe.

Comment: well that definitely means it's getting saved

Comment: I found the problem now. I used \dt to list my tables. I was doing a select * from MyUser; But the rows are in myapp_myuser. Thanks so much for helping me to debug.